# Method to solve this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, problem-solving

This is a [follow-up to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398243/method-request-can-this-equation-be-solved). Assume I have the following system:

$$\nabla\left(f(x)\frac{1}{2}\nabla u(x)^2\right)=v(x)$$

where $\nabla$ is the [Nabla-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del) in some $d$-dimensional space, and $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are some known functions $\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. For simplicity's sake (if it is helpful), we can assume that I want to solve this problem on a discretized grid, and that I can evaluate the partial derivatives numerically through finite differences.

**Now my question:** Is there a way I can find $f(x)$ given this equation, $u(x)$ and $v(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some candidates for a solution.
Every nice function $v$ is a divergence, since you have
$$
 v(x) = {\rm div}\big(\int_0^1 t^{n-1}xv(tx)dt\big).
$$
This is part of the Poincar'e Lemma, for which see Spivak's
Calculus on Manifolds or my exposition at bterrell.net.

Suppose your equation has a solution. Then
$$
 f\tfrac{1}{2}\nabla u^2
$$
and
$$
 \int_0^1 t^{n-1}xv(tx)dt
$$
have the same divergence. Therefore they differ by a function
$z$ that has divergence zero,
$$
 f(x)\tfrac{1}{2}\nabla u(x)^2 = \int_0^1 t^{n-1}xv(tx)dt + z(x).
$$
So a first candidate for $f$ is to take the case $z=0$ and
solve for $f$ by dividing by $\tfrac{1}{2}\nabla u(x)^2$ wherever that
is not zero.

It looks to me that this is a solution.
So there are many other solutions by taking various functions $z$.

I don't know what happens at points where $\tfrac{1}{2}\nabla u(x)^2$
is zero, or where the domain of $v$ is not starshaped.